# Shifting horizontal/vertical position of display in software

Tags: display, resolution

I have an LCD monitor (a [BenQ XL2420T](http://www.benq.ca/product/monitor/xl2420t/specifications/)) hooked up to a modern NVidia video card via a DVI-D connection and running at its native resolution of 1920x1080. I'd like to change the horizontal and vertical position of the display (which will result in some clipping on one side and "dead space" on the other), but the monitor does not allow these parameters to be adjusted unless VGA input is used, which is not an option. This is an understandable limitation (after all, if your digital image is nicely centered, why would you want to move it?) but an unfortunate one in this context.

Accordingly, is there a means to adjust the horizontal and vertical offset of the signal being sent to the monitor in software (e.g., via driver configuration)? Any suggestions would be appreciated, as preliminary googling yielded nothing helpful.

(For the record, this rather unusual modification is required because the monitor forms part of an experimental [stereoscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoscope) assembly.)

Comment: NVidia (and other) graphics drivers sometimes let you specify custom Detailed Timing Descriptors (DTD's) for video output. Such capability may or may not be publicly disclosed. You would typically find these options in the driver software dealing with "Custom Resolutions".  Under Linux, there are the equivalents to DTD's called "modelines".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to alter the settings you require within the NVidia control panel if i understand your question correctly

Comment: Explain how, please.

Comment: The NVidia control panel contains a "Size and position" category, but it only handles resolution and allows the user to specify how non-native resolutions are displayed (e.g., stretch-to-fill, letterboxed, etc.). There's no provision to add an offset to the horizontal and/or vertical position.